# Add non-null unique constraint - not index

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Basically I want to turn this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Computer] ADD  CONSTRAINT [AK_ResourceId] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ResourceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Into not affecting NULL values. The other posts only give an answer to make a unique index, but an index does not create violation when a duplicate value occurs on INSERT. I want a constraint, but I can't seem to make a WHERE statement on this..

Using SQL Server 2014

**Update**

It does work with an index after all :)

SQL:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ResourceId
ON dbo.Computer(ResourceId)
WHERE ResourceId IS NOT NULL;
```

This will create the following error:

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Computer' with unique index 'IX_ResourceId'. The duplicate key value is (1234)
```

Comment: What makes you think the index won't create errors when violated? What do you think it does?

Comment: Do you mean filtered indexes? Do you want to define them with WHERE key IS NOT NULL?

Comment: SQL Server declarative unique constraints always considerers `NULL` values. Your options are either a unique filtered index or indexed view with `WHERE YourColumn IS NULL`. If your unique filtered index doesn't work, add that code to your question.

Comment: I guess I didn't test it enough sorry. It DOES violate with an index.

I get this now: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Computer' with unique index 'IX_ResourceId'. The duplicate key value is (1234).